# Select row and page programmatically in jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTable v1.10.12 and I could easily get the value of the first selected row:

```
var selectedRow = table.rows('.selected').data()[0];
```

The row is also highlighted, so this part is fine.

Now, on some other event not connected to my DataTable, I need to programmatically search a row in the table and select it (i.e. I want to highlight the row), along with its page. I tried the `select()` api this way:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable().select(rowToSelect);
```

where rowToSelect is exactly the same as my previous selectedRow variable, which is in the table, but it does not work (nothing happens).
Concerning the page, I tried

```
$('#myTable').dataTable().page(pageToSelect);
```

Still nothing.

Basically, my scenario is: the user is going back to the Datatable and I want the previously selected row to be still highlighted after redraw.

How can I manage that?

Comment: Do you need current selected row data?

Comment: No, I already have row data. I just want to go through the datatable records and highlight one of them (like it was clicked by the user).

Comment: See example here..https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Comment: I have the feeling that the page you pointed is not addressing my issue: my problem is programmatically searching and highlighting a record in the table, not selecting and highlighting a record after a user clicks on the row. I reworded my OP to clarify this point.

Comment: In Question you are asking for select,didn't mention  searching thing

Comment: I just clarified in my OP that the selection is not on user click on the row, but on some other event not related to the DataTable.

Comment: @Manu how did you programmically select?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to select the row:

```
 $("#myTable").DataTable().row( i ).nodes().to$().toggleClass( 'selected' );
```

Where i is the index of the row.

Comment: This only change the css style of the row, it doesnt really selects the row internally. Try: $('TableId').DataTable().rows(i).select();

Answer (score 0):

For select rows programmaticaly you can use 'select' api function, found here [Select Api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().select())

Some code:

```
$('TableId').DataTable().rows(i).select();
```

Where (i) is the row index.